# How to add restriction in tree structure, It will insert only up to two level of data using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to add restriction on tree structure, It will add up to two level of data. if user add the data then it will provide an message.

```
How can I do it , Here is my table structure

   id       sub_module_id    name
   25            0           Hardware
   26           25           Printer
   27           25           Monitor
   28           26           Inject Printer
```

[image]

Using below recursion function I'm display tree structure..

```
function fetchCompanyCategoryTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '') {

      $cmp_id = USER_ID;
      if (!is_array($user_tree_array))
        $user_tree_array = array();

        $module = new Modulemaster();
        $module->cquery = "SELECT id,sub_module_id,module_name,cmp_id FROM module_master WHERE 1 AND sub_module_id = $parent AND cmp_id = $cmp_id AND is_delete = 0 ORDER BY id ASC";
        $module->action = "get";
        $module_res = $module->process();
        if($module_res['count'] > 0) {
            foreach($module_res['res'] as $module_row_key => $module_row) {
                $user_tree_array[] = array("id" => $module_row['id'], "module_name" => $spacing . $module_row['module_name']);
                $user_tree_array = fetchCompanyCategoryTree($module_row['id'], $spacing . '&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $user_tree_array);
            }
        }
      return $user_tree_array;
    }
```

How can I do it ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simplest answer would be adding a new column for level. This will store modules level. So if "inject Printers" is on 2nd level, the level column will have value 2 for this

So when you add new module, check if the parent module you selected is having level below 2.

Comment: Yes, Its helps to me... Thank you

Comment: Just a suggestion, when you find any answer solved your problem, Please do not forget to mark it as accepted. It will help other people to directly check marked solution and they will try it first! :)